# Python: how to get the next sequence of a list of lists based on a condition?

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, sequence

I used an NLP chunker that splits incorrectly the term 'C++' and 'C#' as: C (NN), +(SYM), +(SYM), C (NN), #(SYM).

The resulting list of incorrect chunking looks like this:

```
l = [['C', 'NN'], ['+', 'SYM'], ['+', 'SYM'], ['C', 'NN'], ['#', 'NN']]
```

I would like to post-process this list, by identifying the strings in index 0 of each list that are 'C' and the next in line '+', '+' or '#'. Then I'd like to concatenate these strings, so that 'C','+','+' becomes 'C++' by simply adding these together. This has to be generalisable, so it should work with lists that contain multiple different words, but still concatenate the desired strings.

desired result:

```
l_desired = [['C++', 'NN'], ['C#', 'NN']]
```

I can identify the items in the list independently (index 0) but I don't know how to go about identifying the desired sequence. My idea was to use the `next()` function, although I do not know where to begin.

Comment: For the sentence: "C++ and C# programming", you get the following original output: "C/NN/B-NP/O +/SYM/O/O +/SYM/O/O and/CC/O/O C/NN/B-NP/O #/#/O/O programming/NN/B-NP/O"  --> which is why I made those lists, so that its easier to work with and post-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the list and check if the first element is a letter, in this case append as a new item, else update the last item:

```
from string import ascii_letters

letters = set(ascii_letters)

out = []
for e in l:
    if e[0][0] in letters:
        out.append(e.copy()) # making a copy not to affect original list
    elif out: # this is to check that out is not empty (edge case)
        out[-1][0] += e[0]
```

Or using a blacklist of symbols:

```
symbols = set('+#')

out = []
for e in l:
    if e[0] in symbols and out:
        out[-1][0] += e[0]
    else:
        out.append(e.copy())
```

output:

```
[['C++', 'NN'], ['C#', 'NN']]
```

Comment: This is working great so far, although could we include the condition to append to the previous letter only if its 'C', since I would not want to combine symbols to previous letters when not needed.

Comment: you can access the last letter with `out[-1][0]` or `out[-1][0][0]` for only the first char, you can make a condition on this ;) (`out[-1][0] == 'C'`)

Comment: So how does this work for the input `#C+` for example :)

Comment: @vaizki this doesn't seem to be a valid input, I'd drop the '#' in my case. Easy enough to handle if needed (else clause in my first code or nested test for the second).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive implementation of a generator which will read the original list as an iterator and "tokenize" it (again - naively):

```
def the_generator(l):
    it = iter(l)

    def get_tok():
        x = it.next()
        return (",".join(x),x)

    while True:
        tok1 = get_tok()
        tok3 = None
        if tok1[0] != 'C,NN':
            yield tok1[1]
            continue
        tok2 = get_tok()
        if tok2[0] == '#,NN':
            yield ['C#','NN']
            continue
        if tok2[0] == '+,SYM':
            tok3 = get_tok()
            if tok3[0] == '+,SYM':
                yield ['C++','NN']
                continue
        yield tok1[1]
        yield tok2[1]
        if tok3:
            yield tok3[1]


l = [['Dog', 'NN'], ['C', 'NN'], ['+', 'SYM'], ['+', 'SYM'], ['C', 'NN'], ['#', 'NN'], ['C', 'NN'], ['+','SYM'], ['#', 'NN']]

for x in the_generator(l):
  print(x)
```

The output:

```
['Dog', 'NN']
['C++', 'NN']
['C#', 'NN']
['C', 'NN']
['+', 'SYM']
['#', 'NN']
```

The generator does not convert the list all at once, only as needed. To create a new list all at once you can do `list(the_generator(l))`.

I am stringifying the individual tokens with `join()` to make comparisons simple. The `while True` loop ends naturally when the original iterable ends and `.next()` raises `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I just appended each letter one by one.

When there's a match with the two strings we're looking for ("C++" or "C#"), it will add that value to the list and reset the string.

```
    l = [['C', 'NN'], ['+', 'SYM'], ['+', 'SYM'], ['C', 'NN'], ['#', 'NN']]
    
    l_desired = []
    x, y = "", ""
    
    for item in l:
        if x == "":
            y = item[1]
            
        x += item[0]
        
        if x in ["C++", "C#"]:
            l_desired.append([x, y])
            x, y = "", ""       

print("RESULT: " + l_desired)
# RESULT: [['C++', 'NN'], ['C#', 'NN']]
```

Comment: nice! although, this only works if the list begins exactly the way it is there. What if the list begins with other words e.g. ['Dog', 'NN'], ['C', 'NN']... Is this generalisable?